# regex for getting number after word

Tags: php, regex

i would like to get the error numbers in my error messages. Like

> Opening and ending tag mismatch: en
>   line 44 and goods
>
> Opening and ending tag mismatch:
>   describtion line 40 and categorie
>
> Opening and ending tag mismatch:
>   categorieInfo line 28 and card
>
> Premature end of data in tag categorie
>   line 27
>
> Premature end of data in tag card line
>   2

i want to search all that. For that i need a regex like: get me the word (acutally the number) after the word line. its always line. Since i've never worked with regex. Im reading me into it but until now i have had no luck with that.

Im doing that on php. Please give me some input in that. :) thanks

Comment: show us what you've produces so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want only line numbers, use this:

```
$msg = 'Opening and ending tag mismatch: en line 44 and goods';

if (preg_match('#\bline (\d+)#', $msg, $matches)) {
    echo "line is: " . $matches[0] . "\n";
}
```

If you want to match all line numbers at once:

```
$msgs = <<<EOF
If you want to match all lines in all messages at once:

Opening and ending tag mismatch: en line 44 and goods

Opening and ending tag mismatch: describtion line 40 and categorie

Opening and ending tag mismatch: categorieInfo line 28 and card

Premature end of data in tag categorie line 27

Premature end of data in tag card line 2
EOF;

preg_match_all('#^.*\bline (\d+).*$#m', $msgs, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach($matches as $msg) {
    echo "message: " . $msg[0] . "\n";
    echo "line: " . $msg[1] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: `\\bline (\\d+)` would be slightly better and will not match the 10 inside `A newline 10 which I am not interested in, I want line 20 instead`.

Comment: @xotix it is an _heredoc_, an alternative way of writing long literal strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: okay thanks. i have to register me for give you some rep. is it possible to get just the number, without the line? i'll try it myself or just cut it off somehow. thanks :)

Comment: in the first solution the line is in $matches[0], and in the second it's in $msg[1]

Comment: i mean, if i have   if (preg_match('#\bline (\d+)#', $msg, $matches)) {
   return $matches[0];
  } i get "line 2, line 4, line 5, line 6" etc. but i just ant "2, 4, 5, 6". can i somehow say to the regex, just the numbers?